# Click back button after logout and the application should not be browsed again

Tags: 2010, authentication, cache, browsers

I am currently using SAML token authentication for one of our clients. When I click log-out the session is getting cleared , everything works fine. But when I click the browser back button I can still get in the application. How can I stop this behavior? I don't want the user to see the application once he logs out. I have seen this behavior in most of the banking sites. **IS THIS POSSIBLE ?**
a)Closing browser is not a option.
b)Disable Backbutton is not considered.

Comment: What happens if you try to do any action on the backed page?

Comment: the user is logged out. Suppose a user has entered some personal details , then when i click back button these are visble .

Comment: Working JS : <script type = "text/javascript" >
function disableBackButton()
{
window.history.forward();
}
setTimeout("disableBackButton()",0);
</script>

<body onunload="disableBackButton()" onload="disableBackButton()">
</body>

Answer (score 1):

You could try to close the tab/window with Javascript in your SignOut.aspx page using  `window.close();` SP 2013 already does it like this (bad formatting included):

```
<asp:content contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
<SharePoint:ScriptBlock runat="server">
function _spBodyOnLoad()
{
    window.close();
}
</SharePoint:ScriptBlock>
</asp:Content>
```

It will prompt the user, but there are some (hacky) ways to work around this in some browsers: [How can I close a browser window without receiving the “Do you want to close this window” prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854/how-can-i-close-a-browser-window-without-receiving-the-do-you-want-to-close-thi)

### Edit:

You say the script you posted "works", but not if the user presses the back button multiple times. This behavior is expected because your script just uses the browser history to navigate forward when a user lands on your sign out page, but if the user navigates back past your page before the script runs they'll be back in the site. The only way to prevent this is to close the tab/window or to clear the browser history. Unfortunately, clearing the browser history is not possible via Javascript (as seen in this SO post: [How to clear browsing history using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044554/how-to-clear-browsing-history-using-javascript)) because that would be a security issue (think about it...).

Therefore, your best (and frankly only) working option is to close the tab. That's what Microsoft did in their sign out page, presumably to solve the same problem you're trying to solve.

If you want to redirect the user to a new URL on sign out, get inventive. Open the target URL in a new tab and then close the tab with the SharePoint browsing history. They wouldn't be able to use the back button then.

Comment: I dont want to close the browser because the ask is to redirect to a different url after logout

Comment: Well, technically this would just close the tab, but what do you mean "the ask is to redirect to a different url"? If you don't close the tab the user will always be able to use the back button to return to the site. If you're trying to say that the question is how to redirect to a different url, that was nowhere in your OP... The code I posted is directly from the SP2013 SignOut.aspx page. This is how MSFT tackled the exact same issue that you're facing.

Comment: Current Application : Click logout , user is taken to a "Login page" where user enters his/her credentials and logs in the site again . I am saying " If i click logout and clear session and logout the user ,then user shld not  be able to use the back button to return to the site"

Comment: You should try deleting the browser history then :P

Comment: Could you suggest history clear code/option across all browsers ?

Comment: Working JS : <script type = "text/javascript" >
function disableBackButton()
{
window.history.forward();
}
setTimeout("disableBackButton()",0);
</script>

<body onunload="disableBackButton()" onload="disableBackButton()">
</body>

Comment: But if i type 2-3 times back button , again i am back in site :(

Comment: I've edited my post. Please explain why you downvoted my answer.

Comment: because it was not correct earlier. I will check out the options you suggested but in my first comment stated "I dont want to close the browser because the ask is to redirect to a different url after logout "

Comment: Consider this as Kiosk machine in bank . I am on my banking site ,i have my all details on page . I click logout and new tab opens saying logout -Happy ending . New user comes to the site and opens my tab and sees all my details . Dont you think I am adding additional risk to my site being innovative/inventive here.

Comment: The suggestion I made works like this: You have Tab A open and are accessing your site. You generate browser history during your session in Tab A. The user clicks "Sign Out", from javascript in Tab A you open a new tab, Tab B, with your desired log out page and then close Tab A. The user now has Tab B only with no browsing history on this tab. If this isn't secure enough maybe you should go back to the drawing board and reconsider your use of SharePoint for this.

Comment: i had tried your option ,but there is a problem when it comes to the Mozilla browser . JS on click of logoff anchor tag with target="_blank" called the Javascript window.open('','_self').close(); . Works good on IE and Chrome though .. Any suggestions on Mozilla browser and clearing the Sharepoint history?

Answer (score 0):

Logout Code : AJAX Implementation in master page ,works with mozilla , Chrome , iE , safari

```
<head runat="server">
<script>
     var httpRequest;        
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Chrome, Mozilla, Safari, ...
         httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     if (!httpRequest) {
         alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');            
     }
     httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
     httpRequest.open('POST', 'https://Logoutworking.site.com/xyz/SitePages/Home.aspx');
     httpRequest.send();

     function alertContents() {
         if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
             if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
             var v = httpRequest.responseText;
                 if(v.indexOf('Access Error') == -1)
                     window.location.replace("https://AABC/aCCESSsError.aspx");
                     } 
                     //else {
                 //alert('There was a problem with the request.');
            // }
         }
     }
</script>
```

OR 
if DISABLE BACK on entire site :

```
<script>
    if (document.URL.indexOf('abc.com') != -1) 
 {
    function noBack()
    {
         window.history.forward()
    }
    noBack();
    window.onload = noBack;
    window.onpageshow = function(evt) { if (evt.persisted) noBack() }
    window.onunload = function() { void (0) }
}
</script>
```